# Something missing in my C# custom config implementation

Tags: c#, custom-configuration

I've tried to write an application with custom config implementation - for this purpose I had written down a small dummy app which I could later follow. But, I'm just not able to load the config. Any ideas on what I'm missing here would be of real help.

**Config File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <!-- Configuration section-handler declaration area. -->
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="SecuritySettingsGroup">
            <section name="SecuritySettings" type="ConfigSecHandler.ServicesSection, ConfigSecHandler"/>
        </sectionGroup>
        <!-- Other <section> and <sectionGroup> elements. -->
    </configSections>
    <!-- Configuration section settings area. -->
    <SecuritySettingsGroup>
        <SecuritySettings>
            <ServiceSecuritySettings>
                <Service svcName="xStore" svcUser="user1" svcPermissions="pemission1"/>
                <Service svcName="xStore" svcUser="user2" svcPermissions="pemission3"/>
            </ServiceSecuritySettings>
        </SecuritySettings>
    </SecuritySettingsGroup>
</configuration>
```

**Classes**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml;

namespace ServicesConfigSection {
    public class ServicesSection : ConfigurationSection {

        [ConfigurationProperty("ServiceSecuritySettings", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
        [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ServiceCollection),
            AddItemName = "Service")]
        public ServiceCollection Services {
            get { return (ServiceCollection)this["ServiceSecuritySettings"]; }
            set { this["ServiceSecuritySettings"] = value; }
        }

        public static ServicesSection GetConfiguration() {
            return GetConfiguration("SecuritySettingsGroup/SecuritySettings");
        }

        public static ServicesSection GetConfiguration(string section) {
            return ConfigurationManager.GetSection(section) as ServicesSection;
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ServicesConfigSection {

    public class ServiceCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection {

        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement() {
            return new ServiceElement();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element) {
            return ((ServiceElement)element).SvcName;
        }

        public override ConfigurationElementCollectionType CollectionType {
            get { return ConfigurationElementCollectionType.AddRemoveClearMap; }
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ServicesConfigSection {
    public class ServiceElement : ConfigurationElement {

        [ConfigurationProperty("svcName", DefaultValue = "", IsRequired = true)]
        public String SvcName {
            get { return (String)this["svcName"]; }
            set { this["svcName"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("svcUser", DefaultValue = "", IsRequired = true)]
        public String SvcUser {
            get { return (String)this["svcUser"]; }
            set { this["svcUser"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("svcPermissions", DefaultValue = "", IsRequired = true)]
        public String SvcPermissions {
            get { return (String)this["svcPermissions"]; }
            set { this["svcPermissions"] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using ServicesConfigSection;

namespace TestApp {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            ServicesSection svcConfig = ServicesSection.GetConfiguration();
            foreach (ServiceElement thisConfig in svcConfig.Services) {
                Console.WriteLine(thisConfig.SvcName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error Faced during loading the XML**

System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled
  Message=An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for SecuritySettingsGroup/SecuritySettings: Could not load type 'ConfigSecHandler.ServicesSection' from assembly 'ConfigSecHandler'. (######\TestApp\bin\Debug\TestApp.vshost.exe.config line 6)

**Vhost Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration>
<!--  Configuration section-handler declaration area.  --> 
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="SecuritySettingsGroup">
<section name="SecuritySettings" type="ServicesConfigSection.ServicesSection, ServicesConfigSection" /> 
</sectionGroup>
<!--  Other <section> and <sectionGroup> elements.--> 
</configSections>
<!--  Configuration section settings area.--> 
<SecuritySettingsGroup>
<SecuritySettings>
<ServiceSecuritySettings>
<Service svcName="xStore" svcUser="user1" svcPermissions="pemission1" /> 
<Service svcName="xStore" svcUser="user2" svcPermissions="pemission3" /> 
</ServiceSecuritySettings>
</SecuritySettings>
</SecuritySettingsGroup>
</configuration>
```

http://db.tt/qH5rJx2D [- Application Structure & Properties](http://db.tt/qH5rJx2D)

Comment: What's your TestApp.vshost.exe.config file look like? Have you tried to clean your solution and rebuild? Or deleting the bin folder and rebuilding?

Comment: Is the namespace correct? type="ConfigSecHandler.ServicesSection

Comment: @prmech - Yes I've tried cleaning my colution and rebuilding it. I alos tried deleting the Bin folder but it didn't work either. Added my vhost config.

Comment: @stepandohnal - I believe so, I've updated some more data. Could someone please check and help me out here. I'll be trying to do some more research today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some more research landed me here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

The very last comment in the above link told me the exact story. The app.config should have fully classified class name as type:-

```
<section name="SecuritySettings" type="ServicesConfigSection.ServicesSection, ConfigSecHandler"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `ConfigSecHandler` in your code.  Try changing your Xml to

```
type="ServicesConfigSection.ServicesSection, ServicesConfigSection"
```